# How to add HLS support to Flex 4.6 project

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, osmf

guys. I want to add HLS video support to custom Flex based video player.
I found OSMF [plugin](https://github.com/denivip/osmf-hls-plugin) which adds HLS support to OSMF 2.0 based players. After adding plugin's swc to build path(I am using FlashBuilder) blank screen is shown no metter is it hls or f4m source.